# Transferring matrices and vectors from R to Python

Tags: python, r, matrix

I have some large matrices and vectors calculated in R. I want to transfer this data to Python (2.7) in order to do some further data analysis.

What is a recommended way to do this?

I am very familiar with R, but a beginner in Python.

Comment: ehm, export as csv?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do, consider `pandas`. It's got some R-like features and powerful ways of ingesting data, from CSV files inter alia. It's built on top of `numpy`, which might also be interesting. If you go this route, come back with specific questions here; this one is too general for this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `write.csv(matrix, "~/filename.csv)` in R and then in Python either (if you want to use pandas)

```
import pandas as pd
new_matrix = pd.read_csv("~/filename.csv")
```

or (if you want to use numpy)

```
import numpy as np
new_matrix = np.genfromtxt("~/filename.csv", delimiter = ",")
```